# How can I express "Something happened while something else was going on" in Spanish?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

¿Cuál es correcto para indicar la idea "Something happened while something else was going on"?

> No vi nada mientras estaba corriendo.

o

> No vi nada mientras corrí.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para responder esta pregunta primero es necesario entender el tiempo verbal copretérito. Este tiempo indica:

> 1. Una acción pasada que sucedió al mismo tiempo que otra.
> 2. Una acción pasada que no se sabe cuando terminó o que no ha terminado.

Basándome en el ejemplo y en el título de la pregunta, infiero que estamos en el primer caso. El primer ejemplo es típico del copretérito puesto que la acción pasada es el no haber visto nada al mismo tiempo que se estaba corriendo.

De manera un poco más simplista podemos ver que el tiempo es copretérito por la terminación "aba" del verbo "estar", las dos terminaciones de este tiempo son "aba" e "ía".

Para expresar la misma idea en la segunda frase, lo único que tenemos que hacer es conjugar la segunda acción también en copretérito y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

> No ví nada mientras corría.

Aquí estamos usando la terminación "ía" del verbo correr y de esta forma las dos frases son equivalentes con la única diferencia que la primera usa el verbo compuesto "estar corriendo" y la segunda sólo usa el verbo "correr".

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta de Sergio es muy exhaustiva. Aun asi, doy mi opinión sobre "uso habitual":

- No vi nada mientras estaba corriendo : Me suena perfecto. El "mientras" indica una acción de una cierta duración, así que el "estaba corriendo", que indica una acción que quizá aún no hubiera terminado, suena perfectamente.
- No vi nada mientras corrí : Suena muy forzado, no se usa. En todo caso, sería más correcto "no vi nada mientras corría", y en ese caso la diferencia es muy sutil.

Para la sutil diferencia entre esos dos casos, quizá otro ejemplo la aclare más:

- Le vi cruzando la calle (observé la acción completa)
- Le vi cruzar la calle (observé un instante, pero no desde el principio hasta el final).

Así que, en este caso, "corriendo" = OK, "corrí" = incorrecto, "corría" = correcto, con una pequeña diferencia de significado (acción más breve, menos continuada).

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, and I think "No vi nada mienstras estaba corriendo" is the best, because I saw nothing *the entire time* I was running.

Answer (score 0):

Si Luisa no estaba corriendo...no puedo decir que corría en esa fecha.. Ella sí.

si yo afirmara que Luisa Corría.. ella podría decir que, en efecto estaba corriendo cómo yo no digo que viera....y ella quiere que imagine... o solo diga que  ella sí corría.....y que el que no la vio fui yo.

Ni la ví, ni me vió y solo ella estuvo corriendo mientras yo no corría porque estaba viendo quién veía... lo que estaban diciendo los que anunciaban... un espectáculo...a las 7: 15... Y no fui, por no correr

NO VI NADA MIENTRAS CORRÍA.. se contradice. Porque corría es una descripción imperfecta que no data... aunque lo intenta... Mientras que estaba corriendo es una forma perifrÁstica y la perÍfrasis explica cómo, cuándo y dónde.. SI UTILIZAS UN PRETÉRITO INDEFINIDO SIN FECHA O CIRCUNSTANCIA TEMPORAL ( LOS GERUNDIOS PUEDEN SERLO, complementos circunstanciales) NO HAS CONSTRUIDO UNA ORACIÓN ... NI UN ENunciado...AUNQUE HAYAS DICHO UNA FRASE SIN SENTIDO COMPLETO, NO ORACIONAL.no gramatical, sin sintáctica, ni lógica... por mas que sea expresión de un momento oral..

Es importante, esa duda, sí... si te interesa seguir colaborando, please...Aquí hay modo que describe la manera (y no en todas las entradas)

Cómo ya habrás observado, en una semiótica descriptiva se pueden combinar formas orales con las verbales.... PERO SOLO LA DRAMÁTICA PERMITE expresar la subjetividad ajena, de modo oral, sin mentir en manera. (PUEDE IR EN MANERA ESCRITA EL MODO ORAL REFLEJADO)  ..¿DUDAS POR EL ORDEN?? ...¿pUEDE LA MATERIA SIN MATEMÁTICA NI CONCEPTO TENER FORMA? ¿tIENE EL CAOS FORMA?.... eL CONCEPTO Y EL MODO ESTÁ MAS CERCANO, EN ÓRDEN TEMPORAL A LA MATEMÁTICA DE LA MATERIA, QUE LO ORAL MANERA..... UN CAOS LINDO QUE REFLEJA LA MANERA EN LA QUE VEMOS EL CÓMO QUE O NO TIENE CONCEPTO...O NO HA SIDO PERCIBIDO COMO TAL. ¿No lo es por ello?.. Manera tiene...¿el concepto?... LUEGO LA MANERA ES EL AUXILIAR...

y VOLVEMOS A LA ETERNA PREGUNTA DE SI LO QUE DETERMINA LA VIDA ES LA CAUSA ÚLTIMA O LA PRIMERA.... SIN QUE TENGA QUE SER ALGO CIRCULAR LA LÓGICA QUE MUEVE LOS HECHOS Y LOS ENUNCIADOS QUE LOS EXPLICAN... O DESCRIBEN... (LA DESCRIPCIÓN ES IMPERFECTA, ABIERTA, NO FINITA, MUY SUGERENTE. NO NECESITA DE AUXILIAR, AUNQUE PUEDE CON ELLO CONVERTIRSE EN ALGO MAS ALLÁ DE LA PERFECCIÓN (en el pluscuamperfecto) ....dicen los lingüistas...que, sin discriminar, distinguen entre lo oral y lo verbal.... en verdad que a fuerza de expresiones y sin verbalizaciones... no te entiende... ni el espejo..que refleja mucho tu cómo...a su manera.

Comment: Por favor, haz el contenido más legible usando párrafos para separar el texto y negrita o itálica en lugar de mayúsculas. Y por favor, deja de firmar los post añadiendo un enlace a tu web personal, ya que no es relevante para el contenido del post.